# Rendering page from web site on Android

Tags: android

is there a way to render the web page from web site and display on the `Textview` control or any other control that supports?

Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

i am just looking to make an android app that basically reads the page from the site and render it on the phone.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have to Use Webview to render a webpage. Here a sample code from google

http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Samples/WebViewDemo/src/com/google/android/webviewdemo/WebViewDemo.java